# stop execution until jquery post is done

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with $.post here is my code:

```
$("#datepicker").click(function () {

    var id = $("#doctor_book").val();
    var url = $('#base_url').attr('data-url') + 'index.php/home/disable_days';

    $.post(url, { id: id }, function (r) {

        r = JSON.parse(r);

        var obj = {
            Mon: 1,
            Tue: 2,
            Wed: 3,
            Thu: 4,
            Fri: 5,
            Sat: 6
        };

        var specific = new Array();
        var final_array = new Array();

        for (var a = 0; a < r.length; a++) {
            for (var b = 0; b < Object.keys(obj).length; b++) {
                if (r[a] === Object.keys(obj)[b]) {
                    specific.push(Object.keys(obj)[b]);
                }
            }
        }

        for (var c = 0; c < specific.length; c++) {
            delete obj[specific[c]];
        }
        for (var key in obj) {
            final_array.push(obj[key]);
        }
        console.log(r);

        yverebi(final_array);
    });
});

function yverebi(final_array) {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var day = date.getDay();
            return [$.inArray(day, final_array) == -1]
        }
    });

    $('#datepicker').datepicker("show");
}
```

r looks like this ["Mon", "Sat"], I saw examples of stopping ajax request and then executing some other functions but what I want is to stop running javascript code until post request is done.

Comment: Add `async:false` flag to the ajax call, but that kinda defeats the whole purpose of asynchronous call.

Answer (score 0):

> to stop running javascript code until post request is done

This is not how it works. Once you run some code, it runs. The POST is asynchronous, which means your remaining code will not (and will never) wait for it.

What you actually do is define a callback function (you have that already, it starts at `function(r){ ...`). This function and all the code inside is run after the POST finished.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery post's different callback methods.

```
$.post( "example.php", function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
});
```

which ever method you want.I think for your case you can use done() method.

you can change your code to

```
 $.post(url, { id: id })
   .done(function(r){
    // your code
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is called a promise. Whenever an async task is done then post it's completion the follow up tasks are executed using promises.

This same thing can be used in your own custom functions also sometimes.

[Reference Article](http://www.bitstorm.org/weblog/2012-1/Deferred_and_promise_in_jQuery.html)

Comment: It's impossible to stop code flow in javascript specially in async code flows. That is why we use promises to write our followup code in them

Answer (score -1):

You can use a "busy" variable :

```
var busy = false; 

$.post(url, {id: id}, function(r){
  if(busy) return false;
  var busy = true;
  /*rest of your code*/

 /* on your $.post callback : */
 var busy = false;
```

Comment: Am I right in assuming that this won't stop the next line after `$.post(...)` from executing before a response is received?